# How to avoid "ClientRedirectError: loop detected" error during testing Flask application (and how is it triggered)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, redirect, flask, flask-testing

Environment:

- Python 3.6.1
- Flask 0.12.2
- Werkzeug 0.14.1

---

While writing tests for my [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) application, I have discovered the following peculiarity: if in tests for Flask application you will be redirected to the same url two times *'in a row'* `ClientRedirectError: loop detected` will be thrown, even if it stops redirecting after the second redirect (i.e. loop is not, actually, happening).

Consider the following, simplified, example:

**app.py**

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    url_for,
    session
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'improper secret key'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if not session.get('test', False):
        session['test'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        return "Hello"

@app.route('/redirection/')
def redirection():
    # do something — login user, for example
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

**test_redirect.py**

```
from unittest import TestCase
from app import app

class RedirectTestCase(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.test_client = app.test_client()

def testLoop(self):
    response = self.test_client.get('/redirection/', follow_redirects=True)
    self.assertTrue('Hello'.encode('ascii') in response.data)
```

Now, if I will run the test — it'll throw a `ClientRedirectError: loop detected` (even though, it could be seen from the code that second redirect will happen only once).

If I just run the app and go to the `/redirection/` — it takes me to the index (i.e. `/`) with no problem, and no looping is happening.

The reason I need `if not session.get('test', False):` in `index()`, is because in my app I'm using it to set some things in `session`, in case user accessing `/` for the first time. As suggested by comment in code, in my 'real' app `redirection()` is a function that logs user in.

---

My questions are:

1. Is there a 'right' way to overcome throwing of `ClientRedirectError: loop detected` in similar cases (i.e. is it possible to make the test run & pass)?
2. Is there a better/'more correct' way to setup things in `session` for the 'first-time' user?
3. Can mentioned behaviour be considered a bug in [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) (i.e. actual looping is not happening, but `ClientRedirectError: loop detected` is thrown, still)?

---

**Workaround**, I have came up with (*which does not answer my questions, still*):

```
def testLoop(self):
    self.test_client.get('/redirection/') # removed follow_redirects=True
    response = self.test_client.get('/', follow_redirects=True) # navigating to '/', directly 
    self.assertTrue('Hello'.encode('ascii') in response.data)
```

This might look redundant, but it's just a simplified example (it'll, probably, make more sense if `self.test_client.get('/redirection/')` would be replaced with something like `self.test_client.post('/login/', data=dict(username='user', password='pass'))`.

Comment: To address questions #1 and #3, see the [Flask documentation on testing sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions). Question #2 is not really suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: @ChapmanAtwell, I have gone through Flask documentation previously (and looked it through, one more time, before writing this comment, just in case =). It does not mention redirection loops, at all (leave alone [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) implementation details), moreover the only section mentioning redirects (tangentially, in fact) is [Logging In and Out] (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#logging-in-and-out). I would argue that question #2 is well suited to post on StackOverflow as it asks about best practices, in particular programming problem.

Comment: @ChapmanAtwell I also didn't get, how redirection loop is related to sessions, directly. It just happened so, that, in my case, `session` is involved in triggering (or not triggering) the redirect — there are, probably, other ways to do it, with the same result. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, I am ready now (almost 1.5 yeast after posting them) to [answer my own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

1. **It is** possible to make test run & pass.

   Given the code, as it is above, the workaround, provided at the end of the question will do, though it can be shortened to:

   ```
   def testLoop(self):
       response = self.test_client.get('/', follow_redirects=True) # navigating to '/', directly 
       self.assertTrue('Hello'.encode('ascii') in response.data)
   ```

   in this particular case, there is no need for the `self.test_client.get('/redirection/')`, line.
    Though, if some changes were made to `session['test']` inside the `/redirection/`, like so:

   ```
   @app.route('/redirection/')
   def redirection():
       session['test'] = True
       return redirect(url_for('index'))
   ```

   then, `self.test_client.get('/redirection/')`, would be necessary, so test would become:

   ```
   from unittest import TestCase
   from app import app

   class RedirectTestCase(TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
       self.test_client = app.test_client()

   def testLoop(self):
       self.test_client.get('/redirection/')
       response = self.test_client.get('/', follow_redirects=True)

       self.assertTrue('Hello'.encode('ascii') in response.data)
   ```

   This, so called, "*workaround*" is just preventing test from doing two redirects to `/`, in a row (which is exactly what is causing `ClientRedirectError: loop detected` — see answer to point 3, below).
2. If there is a better way or not — will depend on the exact details of the app implementation. In the example from the question, the redirection inside `index` is, actually, unnecessary and can be removed:

   ```
   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       session['test'] = session.get('test', True)
       return "Hello"
   ```

   Such change, by the way, will also make the initial test (from the question) pass.
3. As far as I can tell, such behaviour is "by design", namely: `ClientRedirectError: loop detected` is raised, when redirection to the same url occurs (at least) two times in a row. Below are some examples.

   This, test won't encounter `ClientRedirectError` (as redirection only happens once):

   **isolated_app.py**

   ```
   from flask import (
       Flask,
       redirect,
       url_for,
       session
       )

   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.secret_key = 'improper secret key'

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       session['test'] = session.get('test', 0)
       if session['test'] < 1:
           session['test'] += 1
           return redirect(url_for('index'))
       else:
           return "Hello"
   ```

   **test.py**

   ```
   from unittest import TestCase
   from isolated_app import app

   class RedirectTestCase(TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
       self.test_client = app.test_client()

   def testLoop(self):
       response = self.test_client.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
       self.assertTrue('Hello'.encode('ascii') in response.data)
   ```

   Though, if the code of the app will be changed to:

   ```
   from flask import (
       Flask,
       redirect,
       url_for,
       session
       )

   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.secret_key = 'improper secret key'

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       session['test'] = session.get('test', 0)
       if session['test'] < 1:
           session['test'] += 1
           return redirect(url_for('index'))
       elif session['test'] < 2:
           session['test'] += 1
           return redirect(url_for('index'))
       else:
           return "Hello"
   ```

   then test will fail, throwing `werkzeug.test.ClientRedirectError: loop detected`.

   It is also worth mentioning, that triggering of redirection loop errors is different for Flask tests and for real-life browsing. If we will run the last app, and go to `/` in browser — it will readily return `Hello` to us. Amount of allowed redirects is defined by each browser's developer (for example in FireFox it is defined by `network.http.redirection-limit` preference from `about:config`, and 20 is a default value). Here is an illustration:

   ```
   from flask import (
       Flask,
       redirect,
       url_for,
       session
       )

   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.secret_key = 'improper secret key'

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       session['test'] = session.get('test', 0)
       while True:
           session['test'] = session.get('test', 0)
           session['test'] += 1
           print(session['test'])
           return redirect(url_for('index'))
   ```

   This will print `1 2`, and then fail with `werkzeug.test.ClientRedirectError: loop detected`, if we will try to run the test for it. On the other hand, if we will run this app and go to `/` in FireFox — browser will show us `The page isn’t redirecting properly` message, and app will print `1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 21`, in console.